# Has there been any power level figure given in Dragon Ball Super?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

Power levels was a popular idea introduced in Dragon Ball Z. However, after the Freezer saga, I believe there wasnt any power level mentioned in the series or the manga. In the Buu Saga there was a measure of level of energy by Babidi, but it wasnt the same. How about in Dragon Ball Super?

Has there been any power level figure given in Dragon Ball Super?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no power level figure in Dragon Ball Super. The device which was used to measure power level can measure upto a certain limit after which it get destroyed. Also power level increases as the fight keeps on.